# Perl command is not behaving as expected?

Tags: perl, unix, sed

I have a file with below contents:

```
[TEMP.s_m_update_BUS_spec]
$$SRC_STAT_RA=WHG_STATUS_SITEENTSEQCHAIN_20110901094550.dat
$InputFile_RA_SPE=/edwload/rqt/workingdir/status_spe/WHG_STATUS_SITEENTSEQCHAIN_20110901094550.dat

[TEMP.s_m_upd_salions_rqthk]
$$SRC_STAT_RN=WHG_STATUS_SITEENTSEQCHAIN_20110901094550
$InputFile_RN_RQT=/edwload/rqt/workingdir/restriction/WHG_STATUS_SITEENTSEQCHAIN_20110901094550.dat
```

I am using below perl command to just replace `WHG_STATUS_SITEENTSEQCHAIN_20110901094550` with   `WHG_STATUS_SITEENTSEQCHAIN_20110901999999.dat` in the section `[TEMP.s_m_upd_salions_rqthk]`  But somehow its not giving me expected result. Even the `WHG_STATUS_SITEENTSEQCHAIN_20110901094550` under section `[TEMP.s_m_update_BUS_spec]` is getting replaced.

```
perl -p -i -e "s|\$\$SRC_STAT_RN=.*|\$\$SRC_STAT_RN=WHG_STATUS_SITEENTSEQCHAIN_20110901999999.dat|g;s|\$InputFile_RN_RQT=\/edwload\/rqt\/workingdir\/restriction\/.*|\$InputFile_RN_RQT=\/edwload\/rqt\/workingdir\/restriction\/WHG_STATUS_SITEENTSEQCHAIN_20110901999999.dat|g"  Input_File
```

Please let me know the modifications required in command above.Same subsitute commands works fine with SED command. But i wud want to use perl.

Answer (score 1):

The program you run is

```
s|$$SRC_STAT_RN=.*|$$SRC_STAT_RN=WHG_STATUS_SITEENTSEQCHAIN_20110901999999.dat|g;  s|$InputFile_RN_RQT=\/edwload\/rqt\/workingdir\/restriction\/.*|$InputFile_RN_RQT=\/edwload\/rqt\/workingdir\/restriction\/WHG_STATUS_SITEENTSEQCHAIN_20110901999999.dat|g
```

There are a fair number of `$` that should be escaped but aren't. It would be simpler if you used single quotes instead of double quotes. You were probably trying for:

```
perl -i -pe'
   s{\$\$SRC_STAT_RN=.*}{\$\$SRC_STAT_RN=WHG_STATUS_SITEENTSEQCHAIN_20110901999999.dat}g;
   s{\$InputFile_RN_RQT=/edwload/rqt/workingdir/restriction/.*}{\$InputFile_RN_RQT=/edwload/rqt/workingdir/restriction/WHG_STATUS_SITEENTSEQCHAIN_20110901999999.dat}g;
' Input_File
```

Comment: I tried like this by escaping the special characters:    perl -p -i -e "s|\$\$SRC_STAT_RN=.*|\$\$SRC_STAT_RN=WHG_STATUS_SITEENTSEQCHAIN_20110901999999.dat|g;s|\$InputFile_RN_RQT=\/edwload\/rqt\/workingdir\/restriction\/.*|\$InputFile_RN_RQT=\/edwload\/rqt\/workingdir\/restriction\/WHG_STATUS_SITEENTSEQCHAIN_20110901999999.dat|g"  Input_File          ..... But even then its not working as expected.....

Comment: Below are working fine.Thanks for tat
perl -i -pe 's{\$\$SRC_STAT_RN=.*}{\$\$SRC_STAT_RN=WHG_STATUS_SITEENTSEQCHAIN_20110901999999.dat}g;s{\$InputFile_RN_RQT=/edwload/rqt/workingdir/restriction/.*}{\$InputFile_RN_RQT=/edwload/rqt/workingdir/restriction/WHG_STATUS_SITEENTSEQCHAIN_20110901999999.dat}g;' RQT_PROCESS.prm
perl -p -i -e 's|\$\$SRC_STAT_RN=.*|\$\$SRC_STAT_RN=WHG_STATUS_SITEENTSEQCHAIN_20110901999999.dat|g;s|\$InputFile_RN_RQT=/edwload/rqt/workingdir/restriction/.*|\$InputFile_RN_RQT=/edwload/rqt/workingdir/restriction/WHG_STATUS_SITEENTSEQCHAIN_20110901999999.dat|g;' RQT_PROCESS.prm

Comment: But could you please explain me why was the below script didn't work as expected even after escaping special characters:
perl -p -i -e "s|\$\$SRC_STAT_RN=.*|\$\$SRC_STAT_RN=WHG_STATUS_SITEENTSEQCHAIN_20110901999999.dat|g;s|\$InputFile_RN_RQT=/edwload/rqt/workingdir/restriction/.*|\$InputFile_RN_RQT=/edwload/rqt/workingdir/restriction/WHG_STATUS_SITEENTSEQCHAIN_20110901999999.dat|g;"  Input_File

How the interpretation happens?...

Comment: Hi, I have used the command...........................................$perl -i -pe  's{\$\$SRC_STAT_FN=.*}{\$\$SRC_STAT_FN=$OLDEST_FILE_HT_RQT}g;s{\$InputFile_STAT_RQT=/edwload/rqt/workingdir/restriction/.*}{\$InputFile_STAT_RQT=/edwload/rqt/workingdir/status_rqt/$OLDEST_FILE_HT_RQT}g;' .... But $OLDEST_FILE_HT_RQT is not getting evaluated to its value... I am assigning a value before perl to OLDEST_FILE_HT_RQT.

Comment: @Chethan Siddagiri, No, you didn't escape them. Not as far as Perl is concern. Like I said, the program you run is `s|$$SR...`. Change `perl -i -pe` to `echo` to see what the shell passes to `perl`.

Comment: @Chethan Siddagiri, You can either pass `$OLDEST_FILE_HT_RQT` as an argument, or you can use double quotes and escape everything properly this time (`perl -i -pe"s{\\\$\\\$SR..."`).

Comment: @Chethan Siddagiri, Why are you repeating me? Is that a question? All of your messages are completely unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is not working as you want? On my machine, after running your perl code, the file looks like:

```
[TEMP.s_m_update_BUS_spec] $$SRC_STAT_RA=WHG_STATUS_SITEENTSEQCHAIN_20110901999999.dat

[TEMP.s_m_upd_salions_rqthk] $$SRC_STAT_RN=WHG_STATUS_SITEENTSEQCHAIN_20110901999999.dat
```

Ain't this what you expected?

**Edit**

Try modifying your command to:

```
 perl -p -i -e "s|\$\$SRC_STAT_RN=.*?|\$\$SRC_STAT_RN=WHG_STATUS_SITEENTSEQCHAIN_20110901999999.dat|gmx;s|\$InputFile_RN_RQT=/edwload/rqt/workingdir/restriction/.*?|\$InputFile_RN_RQT=/edwload/rqt/workingdir/restriction/WHG_STATUS_SITEENTSEQCHAIN_20110901999999.dat|gmx" Input_File
```

and see if the result is as expected:

```
[TEMP.s_m_update_BUS_spec]
$$SRC_STAT_RA=WHG_STATUS_SITEENTSEQCHAIN_20110901999999.datWHG_STATUS_SITEENTSEQCHAIN_20110901094550.dat
$InputFile_RA_SPE=WHG_STATUS_SITEENTSEQCHAIN_20110901999999.dat/edwload/rqt/workingdir/status_spe/WHG_STATUS_SITEENTSEQCHAIN_20110901094550.dat

[TEMP.s_m_upd_salions_rqthk]
$$SRC_STAT_RN=WHG_STATUS_SITEENTSEQCHAIN_20110901999999.datWHG_STATUS_SITEENTSEQCHAIN_20110901094550
$InputFile_RN_RQT=WHG_STATUS_SITEENTSEQCHAIN_20110901999999.dat/edwload/rqt/workingdir/restriction/WHG_STATUS_SITEENTSEQCHAIN_20110901094550.dat
```

Comment: I tried the command you posted above,  but not giving expected result. My expected result should like below................................................................[TEMP.s_m_update_BUS_spec]
$$SRC_STAT_RA=WHG_STATUS_SITEENTSEQCHAIN_20110901094550.dat
$InputFile_RA_SPE=/edwload/rqt/workingdir/status_spe/WHG_STATUS_SITEENTSEQCHAIN_20110901094550.dat

[TEMP.s_m_upd_salions_rqthk]
$$SRC_STAT_RN=WHG_STATUS_SITEENTSEQCHAIN_20110901999999.dat
$InputFile_RN_RQT=/edwload/rqt/workingdir/restriction/WHG_STATUS_SITEENTSEQCHAIN_20110901999999.dat

Comment: Thanks for the reply!!..I Appreciate it..Btw Please help me with the issue that i have explained above..